# How does the spinglass community detection algorithm implemented in igraph work?

Tags: network-programming, igraph, simulated-annealing

I want to use community_spinglass for my research, but I cannot figure out exactly what it does. I read the reference "Statistical Mechanics of Community Detection", which states that they use simulated annealing, but not exactly how. So I would like to know what update rules are used for the simulated annealing: How are the nodes moved between communities in each time step?

Comment: I am afraid you'll need to read the source code.